# Disabling Syntax Highlighting for Rust Files in Neovim 0.9.x

Tags: vimrc, neovim, lsp

Please find the refined version below:

In the attached images, the top one displays the syntax highlighting performed by the `rust-analyzer` Language Server Protocol (LSP), while the bottom image shows the desired result achieved after disabling the `rust-analyzer` LSP. I personally do not prefer the automatic syntax highlighting, and I find it strange that the behavior of `rust-analyzer` does not seem to provide an option to enable syntax highlighting in the LSP configuration schema.

Previously, when using Neovim v0.8.3, I did not encounter this issue. However, this problem appeared in versions v9.0.0 and v9.0.1.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in turning off the bothersome syntax highlighting. Thank you.
I installed Neovim using the command `sudo apt-get install nvim`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: In order to help us in our tests could you provide, in body of the question, the rust code in textual form that correspond to the screenshot such that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Do you have [Treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) installed?

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by
https://github.com/simrat39/rust-tools.nvim/issues/365#issuecomment-1506286437

The answer the link above have a effect to disable the automatic syntax highlight. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than put junk in your answer, please [edit] to include the actual information (quotes are acceptable with attribution, for example). We prefer QA to stand on its own rather than depend entirely on links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Editted. thanks.

Comment: Stating "the link has the answer" is still not enough. You should include any details necessary to solve the problem directly in the Answer text.